# Make base class method use new child field

Tags: c#, inheritance, polymorphism

I have a class with a method that calls a method on an object which is hidden in the class which inherits it (but the new field is inherited from baseField as well), and I need calls to this method to take place on the new field but when I call childClass.doSomething() I get an exception saying baseField is null.

I think this is because baseField in baseClass is being accessed, which hasn't been instantiated but I'm not really sure

How can I get someMethod to use the ExtendedBaseField when accessed from childClass

```
public abstract class baseClass{

    protected BaseField baseField;

    public void someMethod(){
        baseField.doSomething()
    }
}
```

And a class that inherits it:

```
public class childClass : baseClass{
    protected new ExtendedBaseField baseField = new ExtendedBaseField();
}

new childClass().someMethod(); //null pointer exception
```

ExtendedBaseField inherits BaseField

Comment: What does `protected new ExtendedBaseField baseField` mean?

Comment: @farukdgn if you mean the new keyword before the type, it's to tell the compiler that you are hiding the field in the inherited class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using the new keyword which creates a new field, not set the old one. I am against making fields protected, they should be properties. also you should camel case all properties, methods and classes in .NET. Also brackets should go on their own line.

As per your comments you wanted typed access on your new type so you should make your base class generic. I have demonstrated that as well.

```
public abstract class BaseClass<T>
    where T: BaseField
{
    protected BaseClass(T baseField)
    {
         this.BaseField = baseField;
    }
    protected T BaseField{get; private set;};

   public void SomeMethod()
   {
    BaseField.DoSomething()
   }
}
public class ChildClass : BaseClass<ExtendedBaseField>
{
      public ChildClass() : base(new ExtendedBaseField())
      {

      }
}
```

Comment: I need to access methods in ExtendedBaseField in childClass. Yes - my bad with the class names, just typed it in here this isn't my actual code - and brackets I had that way for brevity...how come protected fields should be properties? I only use properties for public members instead of accessors

Comment: @mbdavis Well you just saw a good reason for it here, I'm making it BaseField protected get but private set so it can only be set by the base class. Also it allows for better refactoring if you want to implement more logic in your getter/setter.

Answer (score 1):

Others have given the correct technical answer: You're explicitly hiding the field in the base class.

I'll speak to the bad practice here, instead.

In C++, there's the concept of RAII.  Resource Allocation Is Initialization. In C#, we don't generally have to think of resource allocation the same way we do in C++, but the pattern of RAII is still a good practice.

All fields declared in a class should be initialized inline

```
protected BaseField baseField = new BaseField();
```

...or in the constructor for that class

```
protected BaseField baseField;
public BaseClass<T>()
{
    this.baseField = new BaseField();
}
```

If that is not possible, then use an abstract property instead of a field, which forces the child class to implement and initialize it.

```
protected abstract BaseField BaseField { get; }
```

Answer (score 0):

The child class is *hiding* `baseField`:

```
protected new ExtendedBaseField baseField = new ExtendedBaseField();
```

This creates a `new` `baseField` property, so the child class can no longer see the base class' `baseField` property.  Thus, it's never set.  Thus, it's `null`.

Don't hide the base class' field.  If you want the base class to use it, have the child class use it to:

```
public class childClass : baseClass {
    public childClass() {
        baseField = new ExtendedBaseField();
    }
}
```

Comment: but then my childClass will see baseField as BaseField when I want it to use methods in ExtendedBaseField...this would mean I then have to cast baseField every time I want to use ExtendedBaseField methods, is that the best way?

Comment: @mbdavis: I don't know what you're trying to accomplish, so I really can't advise on what's "the best way".  But it does sound like there's a Liskov Substitution Principle violation going on here.  It's possible that an inheritance model isn't the right approach to begin with here.

Comment: I'll second what @David said.  What you might want to do is define an abstract method on BaseClass call DoSomething().  ChildClass will then implement that method by calling extendedBaseField.DoSomething().  BaseClass would then not even have baseField at all.